# How can I remove "Where from" information from downloaded .mkv file?

Tags: mojave, metadata

I have downloaded an .mkv files from Safari. When I open "Info" in Finder on the file, I see the following link to where it was downloaded from:

[image]

How can I remove that metadata from the file?

Comment: In Terminal, type `man xattr` and press _enter_. Read the manual page.

Answer (score 32):

The link listed in "Where from" is stored as an extended attribute named "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms" on the file in the file system - it is not actually saved within the .mkv file itself.

You can remove it by opening Terminal.app and running the following command:

```
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms filename.mkv
```

where `filename.mkv` is to be replaced with the actual path and name of the file. The easiest way to do that is simply to write the first part of the command, and then drag the .mkv file into the Terminal.app window.

Comment: If that can help anyone else looking for removing those data recursively in a folder, the -r parameter should be added:
`xattr -r -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms /Folder`

Comment: I get "No such xattr: com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms"