# Unable to Add "Where from" Metadata with Special Characters Using Applescript

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, metadata

Trying to add the "Where from" metadata in the Finder's "Get info" section of a picture on the Desktop and I am not able to since the text has special characters.

In this case, it is "?" and "=" that are present in "theURL_1". As you can see, I have removed these characters on "theURL_2" and it works just fine.

What would be the solution to include the full URL in the metadata?

```
set theFile to POSIX path of (path to desktop folder) & "cat.jpg"

set theURL_1 to "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtH9Yllzjcc"
set theURL_2 to "https://www.youtube.com/watchvEtH9Yllzjcc"

do shell script "xattr -w 'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms' " & quoted form of theURL_1 & space & quoted form of theFile
```

Comment: AIUI that xattr is supposed to hold a binary property list data structure, not a plain string. It appears it sometimes tolerates a plain string, but not always.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So what you saying is that it is not possible to add the Youtube URL to the where from metadata using my approach? I ask because I have seen other applications add it without an issue. What method should be used to accomplish this?

Comment: Your script does work, the `whereFroms` attribute is added, it apparently just doesn't show up in the **Get Info** window (it doesn't in my Mojave test anyway).  As mentioned, maybe the Finder is expecting a property list - to give that a try, check out [my answer to a similar topic](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386599/manually-enter-where-from-text-for-screenshot-metadata/386608#386608) (note that the script is expecting a _list_ of input file items).

Comment: @red_menance, how do you know it was added? It is not even showing up in my Display Metadata List script: (set theFile to choose file
do shell script "mdls " & quoted form of POSIX path of theFile)

Comment: I cheat and use a utility that I wrote, but from **Terminal** you can use `ls -ld@ /path/to/file` to show extended attributes, and `xattr -p com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms /path/to/file` to get the value of the whereFroms attribute (if it is there).