# Batch add or edit the 'Where from' extended attribute

Tags: metadata, extended-attributes

I'm looking to do something similar to [Manually enter "Where From" text for screenshot Metadata?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/386599/manually-enter-where-from-text-for-screenshot-metadata) except I would like to add or edit the existing 'Where from' metadata.

For example when I save a file from the browser, it will have 2 strings in the 'Where from' attribute:

- Purple box is the website url where it was saved from
- Green box is the file url

[image]

1. I hope to batch edit the website url (purple box). For example
   it is originally `website.eg/1`, I want to batch edit them to
   `website.eg/2`
2. Alternatively if the above is impossible, is there a way we can batch add website url string if the existing metadata only have file url (green box) string.
3. I hope I can truncate existing metadata url. For example it is originally `website.eg/file.ext?averylongunecessarystring`, I want to batch edit and truncate every character after the file extension to just `website.eg/file.ext`. I've tried the method [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/386606/500318) using `xattr` in terminal to see if it will add an additional line to preexisting 'Where from' attribute but it didn't, in fact it deleted the exiting 'Where from' attribute instead.